# Concatenate all values between two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I need to concatenate all values in Column A with each individual value in Column B. 
For example

This Dataset:

```
Column A   Column B 
Name       Device1     
Type       Device2     
Date       Device3    
Colour     Device4
           Device5
```

Provides this desired output:

```
Device1Name       Device2Name      Device3Name    
Device1Type       Device2Type      Device3Type  
Device1Date       Device2Date      ... 
Device1Colour     Device2Colour
```

Each one of the columns corresponds to a set of iterations from Column B.

Could you recommend a VBA code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple code that is independent of the number of items located in columns A or B:

```
    Sub ConcatCols()

    'Iterate over all cells in column A, unitl reach to the first empty cell
    Dim ra As Integer
    ra = 1
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(ra, 1))

        'Iterate over all cells in column B, unitl reach to the first empty cell
        Dim rb As Integer
        rb = 1
        Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rb, 2))

            'Concatenate values and write in the next columns at row ra
            Cells(ra, 2 + rb).Value = Cells(rb, 2).Text & Cells(ra, 1).Text

            rb = rb + 1
        Loop

        ra = ra + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub conbineData()
    Dim Cola As Range: Set Cola = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 1)) 'Where this is the first set of data: Name, Type, Date, Colour
    Dim Colb As Range: Set Colb = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(7, 2)) 'Here you have the device: Device1, Device2 and so on
    Dim i As Range
    Dim j As Range
    Dim ac As Integer: ac = 5 'This is because in my example, i have everything in cols A and B
                              'and I want to put the result data in column F (5+1=6)
    Dim bc As Integer: bc = 0 'Here I set this var to 0 because I will add the numbers of the rows in the loop

    For Each i In Colb
        ac = ac + 1 'remember: column F (5+1=6)
        For Each j In Cola
            bc = bc + 1 'Here the rows!
            Range(Cells(bc, ac), Cells(bc, ac)).Value = i & j
        Next j
        bc = 0 'here need to reset the var to from row 1 to the last row/data
    Next i
End Sub
```

Example:

```
+---+-------+---------+
|   | A     | B       |
+---+-------+---------+
| 1 | name  | device1 |
+---+-------+---------+
| 2 | type  | device2 |
+---+-------+---------+
| 3 | date  | device3 |
+---+-------+---------+
| 4 | color | device4 |
+---+-------+---------+
| 5 |       | device5 |
+---+-------+---------+
| 6 |       | device6 |
+---+-------+---------+
| 7 |       | device7 |
+---+-------+---------+
```

Result:

```
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|   | F            | G            | H            | I            | J            | K            | L            |
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1 | device1name  | device2name  | device3name  | device4name  | device5name  | device6name  | device7name  |
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2 | device1type  | device2type  | device3type  | device4type  | device5type  | device6type  | device7type  |
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 3 | device1date  | device2date  | device3date  | device4date  | device5date  | device6date  | device7date  |
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 4 | device1color | device2color | device3color | device4color | device5color | device6color | device7color |
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

### Combine & Concatenate

Copy all four procedures into a standard module. Run the first sub only which will call the other three functions.

```
Option Explicit

' Run only this. Adjust the seven consecutive constants as you see fit.
Sub Combine()
    Const Proc As String = "Combine"
    On Error GoTo cleanError

    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const FirstColumn As Variant = 2
    Const CombineColumn As Variant = 1
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "E1"
    Const Concatenator As String = ""

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet     ' Source Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet     ' Target Worksheet
    Dim First As Variant          ' First Column Array
    Dim Combine As Variant        ' Combine Column Array
    Dim Target As Variant         ' Target Array
    Dim isWritten As Boolean      ' Write Checker

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(srcName)

    ' Write Column Ranges to Column Arrays.
    First = getColumn(wsSource, FirstColumn, FirstRow)
    Combine = getColumn(wsSource, CombineColumn, FirstRow)

    ' Combine Column Arrays to Target Array.
    If IsEmpty(First) Or IsEmpty(Combine) Then Exit Sub
    Target = combineColumns(First, Combine, Concatenator)

    ' Write Target Array to Target Range
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtName)
    isWritten = writeToFirstCell(Target, wsTarget, tgtFirstCell)

    'Inform user.
    If isWritten Then
        MsgBox "Data successfully transferred.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Data not transferred.", vbExclamation
    End If

Exit Sub

cleanError:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred in '" & Proc & "'." & vbCr _
         & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbCr & Err.Description _
           , vbCritical, Proc & " Error"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

' Writes the values of a non-empty worksheet column range
' to a 2D one-based one-column array.
Function getColumn(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                   ByVal ColumnNumberOrLetter As Variant, _
                   Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1) As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(ColumnNumberOrLetter) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Function
    getColumn = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(FirstRow, ColumnNumberOrLetter), rng)
End Function

' Combines two 2D one-based one-column arrays to another 2D one-based array.
' First the first element of FirstColumn will be combined (concatenated)
' with each element of CombineColumn (in the first column of resulting array),
' then the second element of FirstColumn ...etc. The resulting array will have
' as many rows as elements in CombineColumn and as many columns as elements
' in FirstColumn.
Function combineColumns(ByVal FirstColumn As Variant, _
                        ByVal CombineColumn As Variant, _
                        Optional ByVal Concatenator As String = "") As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    ReDim Target(1 To UBound(CombineColumn), _
                 1 To UBound(FirstColumn))
    For j = 1 To UBound(FirstColumn)
        For i = 1 To UBound(CombineColumn)
            Target(i, j) = FirstColumn(j, 1) _
      & Concatenator & CombineColumn(i, 1)
        Next i
    Next j
    combineColumns = Target
End Function

' Writes a 2D one-based array to a worksheet.
Function writeToFirstCell(Source2D1B As Variant, Sheet As Worksheet, _
                          Optional ByVal FirstCellAddress = "A1") As Boolean
    On Error GoTo exitProcedure
    Sheet.Range(FirstCellAddress) _
        .Resize(UBound(Source2D1B), UBound(Source2D1B, 2)) = Source2D1B
    writeToFirstCell = True
    Exit Function
exitProcedure:
End Function
```